# Bluepy Installation Error

Tags: python, serial-port, pycharm, signals, signal-processing

I am trying to install bluepy 1.0.5. However, I get receiving error below.  Any idea how can i solve it? (I am using Mac OS X El Capitan)

> 40:449: execution error: The directory '/Users/isozyesil/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>   The directory '/Users/isozyesil/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>   Command `/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/95/f900ttf95g1b7h02y2_rtk400000gn/T/pycharm-packaging669/bluepy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/95/f900ttf95g1b7h02y2_rtk400000gn/T/pip-djih0T-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile`
>   failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/95/f900ttf95g1b7h02y2_rtk400000gn/T/pycharm-packaging669/bluepy/
>        (1)

Answer (score 8):

You need to install `libglib2.0-dev` and `python3-dev` before:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev python3-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

What part of the diagnostic message did you find unclear?

Did you consider ensuring writable self-owned files by doing `sudo chown -R isozyesil /Users/isozyesil/Library/Caches/pip` ?

Did you consider `sudo pip install bluepy` ?

Comment: Hello @J_H I have tried both, first sudo says, there is no such a file. 

Second one says error below Command 


`"/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-Ly5ltX/bluepy/setu‌​p.py';f=getattr(toke‌​nize, 'open', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-HYzaLE-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-Ly5ltX/bluepy/`

Answer (score 0):

For `python 2.X` this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip libglib2.0-dev
$ sudo pip install bluepy
```

to install dependencies and bluepy.

If you're intending to use it with `python3.x` use `pip3` to install.